# .Net Web Application User Interface (Auto Saving Changes vs. Save Button) Problems

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, webforms, application-design

I was wondering if i could get some opinions with regards to the interface of my web app.

It is an order processing application.  I have simplified the design for the purpose of this question:

1. An order can have many fields (Order Date / Order Contact / Client Number etc)
2. An order has Order Lines (Qty / Product / Price).

When a user creates a draft order, the order is first saved to the `DB` and then an edit screen is shown.
My order items gridview is quite complex and so for ease of use, every time a user re-orders, adds items, removes them or change prices, the changes are made in the `DB`. The order is also autosaved.

However, in the fields below, where client order number and other details are, I cannot auto-save changes as it disturbs the user from easily tabbing from one control to the next.

To get around this, I have a "Save" button which commits the changes.
But this doesn't seem right as it contradicts the autosaving of the order items.

One way around this, I thought, is to house the order items `DataTable` in a session variable and only commit the changes to the `DB` when the user clicks the "Save" button.

Do any of you have views on this method?  Is it acceptable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is primarily opinion based and OP is looking for recomendations instead of an actual solution which can create rather theoretical discussion. On top of that, tags used by OP have nothing to do with an actual problem faced which is highly confusing.

Comment: Many thanks for that, Mateusz.  Are you able to offer any advice as to how I could properly phrase this question, along with the tags I should use?
Thanks again.

Comment: I can advise you to post this question in a different SE page as this site is to solve programming related questions. Your question is more of an architectural/engineering problem with a bit of UX and Web design/development. You can find the one related to your problem [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Thank you for posting the link.  I'll re-post the question on a more suitable site.
Thanks again